# I can sign but am unable to verify SignedXML document in .NET 4.0 using custom SHA256 encryption

Tags: signedxml

Long story short, I can sign documents just fine. But verifying them returns false, every time. I've looked through the first 5 or 6 pages of google and bing for a solution, but every "fix" I've found fails to help. Any help would be appreciated, as I've been trying to tackle this for a little over a week now. Also, the private keys of these certs are NOT exportable, and can't be. I'm not sure if that matters or not. Also, I opted not to include ValidateCertificate for now because it's never once made it that far. It always fails at CheckSignature(). Thank you.

HEre's what I'm using to generate my certs:

makecert -a SHA256 -n "CN=JEA2.me" -pe -r -len 2048 -sy 24 -sky signature -sv jeame2.pvk jeame2.cer

certmgr /add jeame2.cer /s /r localmachine root

makecert -sk "jea2.me" -iv jeame2.pvk -n "CN=JEA2IIS.me" -eku 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.12 -pe -sy 24 -ss my -sr localmachine -len 2048 -sky signature -ic Jeame2.cer IIS-ServerCert-Jeame2.cer

And from here I'm installing them directly into Local machine -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities

```
    private static X509Certificate2 CheckXmldsigSignature(XmlDocument document)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;

        try
        {
            XmlNodeList nodeList = document.GetElementsByTagName("Signature", Xmldsigns);

            if (nodeList.Count != 1)
            {
                Logger.ErrorFormat("Found {0} signature elements in file", nodeList.Count);
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "The XML document must have a single element with local name: \"Signature\" and namespace URI: " + Xmldsigns);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.DebugFormat("Found Signature element successfully");
            }

            RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription.Register();
            var signatureElement = (XmlElement)nodeList[0];
            var signedXml = new SignedXml(document);
            signedXml.LoadXml(signatureElement);

            var keyInfoX509 =
                    (KeyInfoX509Data)
                    (from KeyInfoClause kic in signedXml.KeyInfo where kic is KeyInfoX509Data select kic).Single();

            if (keyInfoX509.Certificates.Count != 1)
            {
                var msg = "The signature must contain information for one certificate.";
                Logger.Error(msg);
                throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.DebugFormat("Extracted X509 certificate data successfully");
            }

            certificate = (X509Certificate2)keyInfoX509.Certificates[0];
            bool validSignature = signedXml.CheckSignature(); //was null parameters. This too does not work.

            if (!validSignature)
            {
                var msg = " SignedXml.CheckSignature returned false.";
                throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.DebugFormat("SignedXml.CheckSignature returned true.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptPro.Common.Logging.LogEx.LogException(Logger, ex);
            throw;
        }

        return certificate;
    }

   private static Stream SignSHA256Stream(X509Certificate2 certificate, Stream stream)
    {
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            Logger.Error("certificate argument is null");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
        }

        if (stream == null)
        {
            Logger.Error("stream argument is null");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
        }

        RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription.Register();

        var document = new XmlDocument();
        document.PreserveWhitespace = true; // May not be necessary.
        document.Load(stream);
        XmlNode root = document.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodeList = document.GetElementsByTagName("Signature", Xmldsigns);

        while (nodeList.Count > 0)
        {
            root.RemoveChild(nodeList[0]);
        }

        Reference reference = new Reference(string.Empty);
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
        CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(24);
        csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
        csp.KeyContainerName = "XML_DISG_RSA_KEY";
        RSACryptoServiceProvider key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
        key.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
        var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));
        SignedXml sxml = new SignedXml(document);
        sxml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        sxml.SigningKey = key;
        sxml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = Xmldsigns256;
        sxml.AddReference(reference);
        sxml.ComputeSignature();

        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = sxml.GetXml();

        if (document.DocumentElement == null)
        {
            document.AppendChild(document.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        }
        else
        {
            document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(document.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        }

        if (document.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
        {
            document.RemoveChild(document.FirstChild);
        }

        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        document.Save(outStream);

        return outStream;
    }
    private static void SignSHA256File(X509Certificate2 certificate, FileInfo file)
    {
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            Logger.Error("certificate argument is null");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
        }

        if (file == null)
        {
            Logger.Error("file argument is null");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
        }

        if (!file.Exists)
        {
            Logger.ErrorFormat("File {0} does not exist.", file.Name);
            throw new ArgumentException("File must exist.", "file");
        }

        if (file.IsReadOnly)
        {
            Logger.ErrorFormat("File {0} is read only.", file.Name);
            throw new ArgumentException("File is read only.", "file");
        }

        FileStream stream = file.OpenRead();

        string s = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s));
        Stream inStream = SignSHA256Stream(certificate, stream2);

        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        inStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        document.Load(inStream);

        Logger.InfoFormat("Saving {0}", file.FullName);

        document.Save(file.FullName);
    }

public class RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription
{
    private const int PROV_RSA_AES = 24;

    public RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription()
    {
        this.KeyAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider";
        this.DigestAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider"; // use System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed for .NET 4.5
        this.FormatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter";
        this.DeformatterAlgorithm = "System.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter";
    }

    public static void Register()
    {
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        var asymmetricSignatureDeformatter = (AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(DeformatterAlgorithm);
        asymmetricSignatureDeformatter.SetKey(key);
        asymmetricSignatureDeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
        return asymmetricSignatureDeformatter;
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureFormatter CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        var asymmetricSignatureFormatter = (AsymmetricSignatureFormatter)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(FormatterAlgorithm);
        asymmetricSignatureFormatter.SetKey(key);
        asymmetricSignatureFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
        return asymmetricSignatureFormatter;
    }
}
}
```

Here are my two XML Files:
1.xml:

```
<node1>
  <node2>
  </node2>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>3nIr0blku+Nsu3FgibCxfQRGBtSmtZL4JGodmaU8blE=    </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>O3ihm7QwE/vh9VZ6CtdENAhB9Ve8jceATCgdJuaQkUHpPWxrG01TftUlrw9a/dQGfW48jJMPngwgcfqnbFspmEEGsBe1xoWQd6mdy2wVRBcQSjqdReNNzs0uQz3/1wPPk4Y2UO+fL+CVNzkIcMpne+t80c2eU4cHBa1WyL5qSlc=</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
  <X509Data>
    <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</node1>
```

2.xml:

```
<metadata>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>wc+6kgUoF9TE7KL1OQXm0EzAIYZuVVc6w3zOKsIY8yU=    </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>MDJn2QLG65LChsJOAN9zKmq4Br5JFSncaTMOmmsmL+DY4xcZt7e4VfI6/IehBkBUzDLeUJHWoE9sp7tVmArBiq/ZFm/ScB2/SRAAD+/NS0XxnxTPjvwu0JsmupNFJ364r/k31TYhI6TBmiCBIdZ6/3qV8LNPtS0iVrMkyhFw6L8=</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</metadata>

public static bool VerifyXmldsigSignature(FileInfo file, bool useSHA256 = false)
    {
        Logger.InfoFormat("Checking Digital Signature and Certificate on {0}", file.FullName);

        bool validCertificate = false;

        if (file == null)
        {
            Logger.Error("file argument is null");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("file");
        }

        if (!file.Exists)
        {
            Logger.ErrorFormat("File {0} does not exist.", file.Name);
            throw new ArgumentException("File must exist.", "file");
        }

        try
        {
            var document = new XmlDocument();
            document.PreserveWhitespace = true;     document.Load(file.FullName);

            DateTime timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;

            bool respectCertExpiration = HasTimestamp(document);

            if (respectCertExpiration)
            {
                timestamp = CheckXadesTimestamp(document);
            }

            var certificate = CheckXmldsigSignature(document);

            validCertificate = ValidateCertificate(certificate, timestamp, respectCertExpiration);

            Logger.InfoFormat("Digital Signature and Certificate passed verification on {0}", file.FullName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = string.Format("{0} failed signature verification.", file.FullName);
            throw;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, there are two places that I can find that might be an issue:

### Certificate Validity.

Using `CheckSignature()` without any parameters requires the signing certificate to be signed by a trusted root authority. As you're already extracting the certificate that is part of the signature I suggest that for testing you change the call to

```
bool validSignature = signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate);
```

Note that you know only validates that the Xml is signed by the certificate info in the file. You have no validation that the signature actually is done by any specific party. I assume you are doing that in the calling function as it returns the certificate.

### Whitespace

In the signing routine you set `PreserveWhitespace=true`. That means that the whitespace will be included in the hash calculation of the signature. Make sure you set `PreserveWhitespace=true` when you load the document for validation too (that part is not included in the posted code, so I don't know).

### References

Finally, you're code is vulnerable to Xml Signature Wrapping attacks, because you are not properly checking the references of the signature. Please see [this blog post of mine](https://coding.abel.nu/2015/12/xml-signatures-and-references/) for examples.

Comment: Thank you Anders for getting back to me. I have tried passing in Certificate to checksignature, using all of the possible overloads. None of them helped. I was also already trying to preserve whitespace. I have included the verification block for your review. Thank you also for the blog post. I'll look at it shortly.

Comment: I also just double-checked. My certificates are sitting in Trusted Root Certification Authority for local computer as well as Current User, and it's still failing. SignedXml.Checksignature keeps returning false. Is there good documentation anywhere as to why it might fail? I can't seem to find anything useful. Thanks again.

Comment: If this is helpful at all, I believe it's failing at " return asymmetricSignatureDeformatter.VerifySignature(hashval, m_signature.SignatureValue);" in private bool CheckSignedInfo (AsymmetricAlgorithm key) in SignedXml.cs line 820. I can't seem to get a value for hashval because it's "optimized" (cannot evaluate expression because the current method is optimized).

Answer (score 0):

Anders, thanks for your suggestions. I finally got my code to verify after several weeks of playing around with it, and I finally got something to work so I wanted to share it with you guys. The verify method is unchanged, and the Xades stuff is custom and not necessary to verify files signed with my code. Lastly, I used the following 2 urls as my starting point, but dozens of pages from google also helped:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/11/14/using-sha256-with-the-signedxml-class/
https://gist.github.com/sneal/f35de432115b840c4c1f#file-rsapkcs1sha256signaturedescription

```
private static Stream SignSHA256Stream(X509Certificate2 certificate, Stream stream)
    {
        if (certificate == null)
        {
            Logger.Error("certificate argument is null");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
        }

        if (stream == null)
        {
            Logger.Error("stream argument is null");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
        }

        RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription.Register();

        var document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(stream);
        XmlNode root = document.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodeList = document.GetElementsByTagName("Signature", Xmldsigns);

        // nodeList is actively updated so we delete element [0] until there are none left.
        while (nodeList.Count > 0)
        {
            root.RemoveChild(nodeList[0]);
        }

        Reference reference = new Reference(string.Empty);
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform()); 
        reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
        reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

        var keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));

        SignedXml sxml = new SignedXml(document);
        sxml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        sxml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
        sxml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = Xmldsigns256;
        sxml.AddReference(reference);
        sxml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315";
        sxml.ComputeSignature();

        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = sxml.GetXml();

        if (document.DocumentElement == null)
        {
            document.AppendChild(document.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        }
        else
        {
            document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(document.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        }

        if (document.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
        {
            document.RemoveChild(document.FirstChild);
        }

        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        document.Save(outStream);

        return outStream;
    }
```